# Swift - reloadData() doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to develop a note-taking app using Xcode 3 and Swift. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var data: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Notes"
        // Add a button (add or edit)
        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNote))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        load()
    }

    // function that says what happens when button is pushed
    func addNote() {
        if table.isEditing {
            return
        }
        let name: String = "Row \(data.count + 1)"
        data.insert(name, at: 0)
        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        table.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    // to set what happens when push edit button
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        table.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        save()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil)
    }

    func save() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func load() {
        if let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String] {
            data = loadedData
            table.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

The line that gives me a problem is `table.reloadData()`. The app pops up on the simulator, but there is no content, and the table doesn't show up. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you set the table view's `dataSource`?

Comment: You are only saving data when you delete rows. So if you add rows and quit the app, nothing will be saved and there will be nothing to load when the app starts again.